# CSS div tags not the size of parent when using percents

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the div tags in my HTML a percent of the size of the parent div, without being too small or too large. What I get when I check the size of the div with this code:

```css
#main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 31%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

.content {
    width: 61%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.sidebar, .content {
    background: #888;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar_inner, .content_inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar_inner">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_inner">
            <h1>Hello again!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: result]

The blue box is the inner div tag. Here is a better picture of the problem

[image]

Comment: You can use `min-width`, `max-width`, `min-height` and `max-height`.

Comment: I tried setting `.sidebar_inner` and `.content_inner` to have:
`min-width: 100%;
max-width: 100%` and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `h1 margin`. Browsers have default style for line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on. However, you can solve your problem by giving `margin:0;` to the `h1` element or use [css reset](http://cssreset.com/) to solve your problem.

```
h1
{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

```css
#main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 31%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

.content {
    width: 61%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.sidebar, .content {
    background: #888;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar_inner, .content_inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: black;
}

h1
{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar_inner">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_inner">
            <h1>Hello again!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Power-Up Games Is it helpful?

Comment: It is very helpful, thank you. I will add a CSS reset to the website.

Comment: I would not recommend resetting your styles altogether, instead I would recommend using https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ and manually removing margin-top from those h1 tags in your example or apply a top padding to compensate this margin to the container.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have units on your width and height such as `px`, `em`, `rem`, `%`, `vh`, `vw`.

- [See more here at
  W3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)
- [Solution from your example](http://codepen.io/pohuski/pen/dYgvJy)

Comment: I just forgot to add the units when typing it in the question, it still doesnt work with them

Comment: Hi Power-Up Games, It appears that the divs `.sidebar` and `.content` _are_ a percentage of the parent container div `#main`. Can you be more clear about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to make .sidebar_inner and .content_inner a percentage of .sidebar and .content respectively.

Comment: This is shown in the updated code snippet and in the second image.

Comment: Also, the 800px was just an example. I am going to use percents to make the final product more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

All the properties of #main require a measurement unit...

```
#main {
width: 800px
height: 800px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

For you example, px is good.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you have a top margin on your H1 tag.